# C# program connected to postgres SQL database

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio, npgsql

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Data.Common;
using Npgsql;
using NpgsqlTypes;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string postgresConStr = String.Format("Server=localhost;Port=5432;UserId=ricards;Password=muzika23;Database=proguzd_4;");
            NpgsqlConnection ncon = new NpgsqlConnection(postgresConStr);
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM personas", ncon);
            ncon.Open();
            NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("vards", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("uzvards", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("vecums", typeof(int)));

            DataColumn[] keyColumns = new DataColumn[1];
            keyColumns[0] = dt.Columns["ID"];
            keyColumns[0].AutoIncrement = true;
            dt.PrimaryKey = keyColumns;

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                row["ID"] = dr["persona_id"];
                row["vards"] = dr["name"];
                row["uzvards"] = dr["uzvards"];
                row["vecums"] = dr["vecums"];
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            ncon.Close();
            dt.AcceptChanges();
            int izvele;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1 - Apskatīt tabulas datus");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - Pievienot tabulai datus");
                Console.WriteLine("3 - Labot tabulas datus");
                Console.WriteLine("4 - Dzēst tabulas datus");
                Console.Write("Jūsu izvēle: ");
                izvele = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (izvele)
                {
                    case 1:
                        PrintTable(dt);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.Write("Ievadiet cilveku skaitu, cik vēlieties pievienot: ");
                        int CilvSk = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        for (int i = 0; i < CilvSk; i++)
                        {
                            DataRow drw = dt.NewRow();

                            Console.Write("Ievadiet studenta vārdu: ");
                            string vards = Console.ReadLine();
                            drw["vards"] = vards;

                            Console.Write("Ievadiet uzvārdu: ");
                            string uzvards = Console.ReadLine();
                            drw["uzvards"] = uzvards;

                            Console.Write("Ievadiet vecumu: ");
                            int vecums = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                            drw["vecums"] = vecums;

                            dt.Rows.Add(drw);
                            ApplyToDb(dt, ncon);
                        }

                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Kuru ierakstu vēlaties labot? : ");
                        int numurs = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        numurs = numurs - 1;
                        Console.WriteLine("Ievadiet jauno vārdu: ");
                        string jaunaisvards = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ievadiet jauno uzvārdu: ");
                        string jaunaisuzvards = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Ievadiet jauno vecumu: ");
                        int jaunaisvecums = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.WriteLine("Vai tiešām vēlaties veikt izmaiņas? (y/n): ");
                        string atbilde = Console.ReadLine(); ;
                        if (atbilde == "y")
                        {
                            dt.Rows[numurs]["Vards"] = jaunaisvards;
                            dt.Rows[numurs]["Uzvards"] = jaunaisuzvards;
                            dt.Rows[numurs]["Vecums"] = jaunaisvecums;
                            ApplyToDb(dt, ncon);
                            Console.WriteLine("Ierakstā veiktās izmaiņas ir sekmīgi izdarītas");
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (atbilde == "n")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Izmaiņas netika ieviestas");
                            break;
                        }

                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.Write("Kuru ierakstu vēlaties dzēst? : ");
                        int ierakstsNr = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        ierakstsNr = ierakstsNr - 1;
                        Console.Write("Vai tiešām vēlaties dzēst šo ierakstu? (y/n): ");
                        string atbilde2 = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (atbilde2 == "y")
                        {
                            dt.Rows[ierakstsNr].Delete();
                            ApplyToDb(dt, ncon);
                            Console.WriteLine("Ieraksts ir veiksmīgi idzēsts");
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (atbilde2 == "n")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Ieraksts netika dzēsts");
                            break;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            } while (izvele != 0);

        }
        static void PrintTable(DataTable dt)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                Console.Write(dc.ColumnName + "   ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dr.ItemArray.Length; i++)
                {

                    Console.Write(dr[i] + "\t");


                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }
        static void ApplyToDb(DataTable dt, NpgsqlConnection ncon)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dro in dt.GetChanges().Rows)
            {

                if (dro.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
                {
                    NpgsqlCommand add = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO persona (name, uzvards, vecums,persona_id) VALUES(@vards,@uzvards,@vecums,@persona_id)", ncon);
                    add.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@vards", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
                    add.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@uzvards", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar));
                    add.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@vecums", NpgsqlDbType.Integer));
                    add.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@persona_id", NpgsqlDbType.Integer));

                    add.Parameters[0].Value = dro[0];
                    add.Parameters[1].Value = dro[1];
                    add.Parameters[2].Value = dro[2];
                    add.Parameters[3].Value = dro[3];
                    ncon.Open();
                    add.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    ncon.Close();

                }
                if (dro.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
                {
                    NpgsqlCommand update = new NpgsqlCommand("UPDATE persona SET vards=@vards,uzvards=@uzvards, vecums=@vecums WHERE persona_id=persona_id ", ncon);
                    update.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@vards", dro[1]));
                    update.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@uzvards", dro[2]));
                    update.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@vecums", dro[0]));

                    ncon.Open();
                    update.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    ncon.Close();
                }
                if (dro.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted)
                {
                    NpgsqlCommand delete = new NpgsqlCommand("DELETE FROM persona WHERE persona_id=persona_id; ");
                    delete.Parameters.AddWithValue("@persona_id", dro[0, DataRowVersion.Original]);
                    ncon.Open();
                    delete.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    ncon.Close();
                }
                dt.AcceptChanges();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have a task, to connect to PostgreSQL database and add, modify, delete, show its info.
I have to use datatables.

The thing here is, I have connected this program to database. It shows information and so on (case 1) but, when I'm trying to add (case 2), modify (case 3) or delete (case 4) data, it shows this -
[image: This code is in ApplyToDb]

I have no idea what to do. I am using NpgSql 2.0 to work with database and program.

Am I even thinking in the right way? With this code, the info I input, modify, delete will automatically change in database?

Please do ask if you need any additional information to help me.
I'm a beginner in programming and I don't know quite well what kind of information to provide.

Comment: your error show's you what the problem is.. There is an error converting string to `DateTime`.

Comment: As a side note, why do you have to use DataTables?

Comment: DateTime? Im not even using anything like that. 
I have to use DataTables because my lecturer set that as an obligation.

Comment: What is your table definition?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/efwisu   i hope this is what you asked for